# Multiple organisation repos and keys - Mac OSX Sierra

Tags: morea-framework

I am trying to creating 3 morea courses as individual organisation repos e.g. course 1, course 2, course 3 in org x.
I do not have a server available to me, using MacBook Pro.
How do I set up multiple keys, 1 for each repo, on Sierra OSX that will enable the morea-publish script to work properly?

Answer (score 0):

As you're probably aware, there is GitHub documentation on deploy keys here:

https://developer.github.com/guides/managing-deploy-keys/#deploy-keys

The Morea publish script simply invokes the 'git' command a few times:

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/morea-framework/scripts/master/morea-publish.sh

So, I don't think the script needs modification. I think your problem is somehow related to a mistake in the way you set up deploy keys.  I looked around and here is some supplemental documentation on using deploy keys:

https://gist.github.com/zhujunsan/a0becf82ade50ed06115

Good luck!